# Chronic parsing of month/day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chronic

I am using Chronic to parse dates and it is parsing the string '8/15' as August 16, 2015.

Any ideas on how I could get Chronic to recognize 8/15 as August 15, current year?

Here is the test code:

```
Chronic.parse('8/15') #=> 'Sun Aug 16 12:00:00 -0400 2015'
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this is specified in the documentation however I would try passing `:context => :past` and see if that helps is parse the string. The documentation for the parse method is located here http://chronic.rubyforge.org/classes/Chronic.html#M000001

Comment: No, I tried that. Did not work :(

Comment: Well, you have a few options you can take to solve this. You can modify the format you are getting data in. You can try to correct this data yourself by appending a year but that will only work if the data is consistently in this format. Or you can try to find another library to parse dates.

Comment: I can't modify the format as the format is inputed by the user. I could use regular expressions to catch this use case and add the year but that seems icky. I may have to check out other libraries.

Comment: Ah! Take a look at the DateTime class in Ruby. There is a way for you to specify your own date format for parsing. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html#M000484

Comment: Why don't you add a Datepicker and you normalize the input? You won't have to deal with people not entering dates correctly...

Answer (score 0):

As an option:

```
irb(main):016:0> Chronic.parse("#{Time.now.year}/8/15")
=> 2011-08-15 12:00:00 +0300
```

Comment: I will have to catch this and use regular expressions. The input is entered by the user and I can't control what is entered into the method.

Comment: I mean that the user may enter '8/15' or 'Aug. 15', etc. So I only want to add the year before the input of the regular expression says that they entered '%d/%d'

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be using the normal DateTime parsing provided by Ruby.
As an example you can parse the date by calling:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > DateTime.strptime("8/15", "%m/%d")
 => #<DateTime: 2011-08-15T00:00:00+00:00 (4911577/2,0/1,2299161)> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 >
```